# Error while executing automation scripts from Robot framework using Python with Selenium - Authentication error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, ui-automation

I am writing this to find a solution for an error I am receiving

I am automating application using Robot framework using Python with Selenium
Below is the versions for information

Python 3.11
Selenium 4.9
robotframework 6.1
robotframework-pythonlibcore 4.2.0
robotframework-seleniumlibrary 6.1.0
Pycharm IDE

The scripts used to work perfectly until few days ago. Now, I see error regarding authentication saying
"Access Denied (authentication_failed)
Your credentials could not be authenticated: "Credentials are missing.". You will not be permitted access until your credentials can be verified.
This is typically caused by an incorrect username and/or password, but could also be caused by network problems.
For assistance, contact your network support team."

When executed, The browser is not opening up.

Wondering it is something to do with Proxy. IF so how could i disable this.
I have attached the image for reference. Appreciate any kind of inputs to resolve this.

Simple script to open Google website:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9R0R.png)

code:

```py
*** Test Cases ***
LoginTest
        Open Browser        https://www.google.com      chrome
        Sleep    15
*** Keywords ***
```

Error I am receiving:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzFTA.png)

I tried installing the framework again with latest version. It didn't work

Comment: Please post the code as text not screenshot.

Comment: No, the suggestions posted does not solves the problem.